# Auto-increment Version Number on Check-in for Team Foundation

Tags: tfs, versioning

I would like to have all project files automatically increment the version number when a change is checked in. Is there a way to configure TFS to automatically increment on check-in or at least execute a script on the project to do it for me?

I understand that in standard practice builds usually increment the version number but this doesn't make too much sense to me as you can have 2 subsequent builds that may not have any differences at all yet the versions will be different.

Comment: Do take into account that what it means to have changes can also include how you build not just the content used for compilation.  If you change your build process to do other activities, that would suggest a new version number.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to get a little into the Workflow Foundation, but I used this very clear description from Richard Banks:

http://www.richard-banks.org/2010/07/how-to-versioning-builds-with-tfs-2010.html

If you know a little C# you can easily edit it to your own needs.